# Get latest one record will show, 1 week after its been added. After that it will show randomly upon page refresh

Tags: date, repeater, where-clause, kentico

My requirement is simple , I have a repeater control webpart, and I want to apply a condition in the `WHERE` clause.

Condition : The latest one record will show, 1 week after its been added. After that it will show randomly upon page refresh.

Means if record is more than 1 week , then it will show latest by , upon page refresh.

I made this query but it doesn't work:

```
(DocumentCreatedWhen >= dateadd(day, -7, convert(date, getdate())))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Jahangir. Did any of the answers work for you or is this still causing you an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused on the "on page refresh" portion of your request.  You said in your first part that "after that it will show randomly upon page refresh" then on the 2nd part said "if the record is greater than 1 week, it will show upon page refresh"

Which do you want?

To filter out events that are at least 1 week old, you would do

DATEDIFF(day, DocumentCreatedWhen , GETDATE()) >= 7

from there you can do an ORDER BY DocumentCreateWhen asc, and a Top # of 1.

If you want to apply different logic on postback, you can use macros and the Visibility to make the "random" repeater visible on post back, and the other visible if it's not postback, or use macros to provide different WHERE conditions based on the postback status.

I could not find a default "IsPostback" macro available so you will have to create a custom macro that returns the current postback status.

Answer (score 1):

Try these settings on your data source:

- **ORDER BY expression:** `age DESC, NEWID()`
- **WHERE condition:** `DateDiff(day,DocumentCreatedWhen, GetDate()) >= 7`
- **Columns:** `CASE WHEN DateDiff(day,DocumentCreatedWhen,GetDate()) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS age, *`

This should mean that any document that is 7 days old appears at the top of your list, ready for you to set **Select top N pages** to `1`.  All other documents *more* than 7 days old will just be ordered randomly by the NEWID() function.

Obviously, where the `*` is in the columns, you should specify the columns that you need rather than leaving in a wildcard for performance reasons.

I just ran this out on the Dancing Goat sample and it does what you need (assuming I've understood correctly).

**Edit:**
Worth noting.  Anything that is 7 days old will stay there until it is... well.. not exactly 7 days old.  To make that work, you would somehow need track that the record has been shown so that you can then exclude it from the results set.  I.e. you **COLUMNS** become something like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN (DateDiff(day,DocumentCreatedWhen,GetDate()) = 7 AND DocumentHasBeenShown=0 THEN 1 
  ELSE 0 
END) AS age
, *
```

Answer (score 0):

What You need to use is union

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
(
-- Get the latest record
Union 
-- Get random record
) as Result
```

For example, if you get MenuItem:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
(
-- latest for this week
SELECT DocumentUrlPath, DocumentName, DocumentCreatedWhen from  (
select top 1 DocumentNAme, DocumentUrlPAth, DocumentCreatedWhen  FROM View_CONTENT_MenuItem_Joined  
where DATEDIFF(day, DocumentCreatedWhen , GETDATE()) <= 7  Order BY DocumentCreatedWhen DESC) as LatestForThisWeek
UNION
-- random
SELECT DocumentUrlPath, DocumentName, DocumentCreatedWhen from  (
select top 1 DocumentNAme, DocumentUrlPAth, DocumentCreatedWhen  FROM View_CONTENT_MenuItem_Joined  
ORDER BY NEWID() ) as RandomizedRecords
) as Result
```

There is lots of sub queries but this will give you the idea :)